# OutOfMemoryException: bitmap exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I uploaded an app (Hungry Birds) to the marketplace and a friend downloaded it for his Xperia x10. He changed the Bitmap from the default, non-animated version to an animated one, and that's when the game crashed. I've intensively tested it on Nexus 1, HTC Magic, HTC Desire and an emulator, and they work fine everywhere else. Why does the Xperia do that? And is there a way to increase the VM budget on specific devices in the code?

EDIT:
Exception is thrown when a resource (png) which is 200kb big is being created, although I mostly only use a smaller, cut-out portion of that (it's big for tablet support).

EDIT2:
Strangely, the code worked on my dev phone (HTC Magic with 2.2 CyanogenMod) when I turned the heap size down to 12mb. As far as I know, the minimum is 16mb. Any ideas why that worked?

BTW: After I implemented the workaround, it suddenly started working on the X10, don't know why. Android is strange..

Comment: there are many question about it in stackoverflow so Please first Search about it after then you didnt got any answer then ask here. [OutOfMemoryException: bitmap exceeds VM budget](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5DOutOfMemoryException:%20bitmap%20exceeds%20VM%20budget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
is there a way to increase the VM budget on specific devices in the code?
```

-This is not possible.

Only solution is to handle the **outOfMemoryException** in your code.

To avoid this **outOfMemoryException** you can follow these two simple things. 
Make your bitmap to be null on each cycle. And you can recycle your bitmap like this, `bitmap.recycle();` once you have finished using your bitmap. This will remove the memory consumed by bitmap.

Comment: As said.. The problem only occurs on x10, and I would like to know why.. But thanks for the tipp with the recycle.

Comment: This is because the VM heap memory varies with devices. So I believe in this case x10 has low VM heap memory. That's the reason you are running into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem several times. The only way I have found to solve this is to measure the amount of memory left on the device in order to scale down (not always possible) or use other kind of degraded modes.

I first get the amount of memory available:

```
final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
final long freeMem = rt.freeMemory() + (rt.maxMemory() - rt.totalMemory());
```

And then I compare this to the size of my resource (can be an image, a sound, anything else...). I generally apply a ratio (from 0.50 to 0.80, but this is a matter of strategy) to avoid consuming all available memory.

```
if (myResourceSize < (freeMem * ratio)) { 
    // use it as it is
}
else {
    // use (or create if possible) something smaller
}
```